# Append each input inside the closed form

Tags: jquery

I didn't write nor have access to change this HTML, and I need to append each input type submit to the prev / closet form . I've tried using closet and prev with not luck, so I ended up giving a class to each tr using eq, then appending each input inside each form, but its an ugly solution no doubt.

I've set up a fiddle with what I have, but there can be countless input and submit on the page and I need a better solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/vyrfpvsy/7/

I get multiple instances when i try this https://jsfiddle.net/vyrfpvsy/60/

```
$('input[type="submit"]').each(
function(){
   $(this).detach().appendTo('.trades-form');
});
```

HTML

```
<table class="table1">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="tablerow">
         <th colspan="7"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="trade-offer">
         <div class="offerer">
            <td><a></a></td>
            <td class="players-offered-by">
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <div class="offeree">
            <td></td>
            <td>
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <span></span>
            <textarea></textarea>
         </td>
         <td class="actions-by">
            <form class="trades-form">
               <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
               <ol type="a">
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
               </ol>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" id="trade_button0">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="trade-offer">
         <div class="offerer">
            <td><a></a></td>
            <td class="players-offered-by">
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <div class="offeree">
            <td></td>
            <td>
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <span></span>
            <textarea></textarea>
         </td>
         <td class="actions-by">
            <form class="trades-form">
               <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
               <ol type="a">
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
               </ol>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" id="trade_button1">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="trade-offer">
         <div class="offerer">
            <td><a></a></td>
            <td class="players-offered-by">
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <div class="offeree">
            <td></td>
            <td>
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <span></span>
            <textarea></textarea>
         </td>
         <td class="actions-by">
            <form class="trades-form">
               <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
               <ol type="a">
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
               </ol>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" id="trade_button2">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="trade-offer">
         <div class="offerer">
            <td><a></a></td>
            <td class="players-offered-by">
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <div class="offeree">
            <td></td>
            <td>
               <ul>
                  <li><a></a></li>
               </ul>
            </td>
         </div>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <span></span>
            <textarea></textarea>
         </td>
         <td class="actions-by">
            <form class="trades-form">
               <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
               <ol type="a">
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
                  <li><input type="radio"></li>
               </ol>
            </form>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" id="trade_button3">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the "form" portion of above HTML to be like this when done for each form

```
        <form class="trades-form">
           <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
           <ol type="a">
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
           </ol>
         <input type="submit" id="trade_button0">
        </form>

        <form class="trades-form">
           <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
           <ol type="a">
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
           </ol>
         <input type="submit" id="trade_button1">
        </form>

        <form class="trades-form">
           <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
           <ol type="a">
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
           </ol>
         <input type="submit" id="trade_button2">
        </form>

        <form class="trades-form">
           <input type="hidden"><input type="hidden"><input type="hidden">
           <ol type="a">
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
              <li><input type="radio"></li>
           </ol>
         <input type="submit" id="trade_button3">
        </form>
```

For testing, and to get something working, I added a class to and appended it to the tr, but I realize this is garbage

```
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer:eq(0)').addClass('tr-index1');
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer:eq(1)').addClass('tr-index2');
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer:eq(2)').addClass('tr-index3');
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer:eq(3)').addClass('tr-index4');

jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index1 + tr input[type="submit"]').appendTo('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index1 .trades-form');
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index2 + tr input[type="submit"]').appendTo('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index2 .trades-form');
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index3 + tr input[type="submit"]').appendTo('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index3 .trades-form');
jQuery('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index4 + tr input[type="submit"]').appendTo('.table1 .trade-offer.tr-index4 .trades-form');
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: I've been over this a couple times and I don't get your meaning.  What are you trying to append to what and why?

Comment: append each instance of the <input type="submit"> to the closest previous  form#trades-form

Comment: Oh I think I see.  The submit buttons are outside the form and you need them inside to trigger the form action, is that close?

Comment: correct !! Thx for taking a look

Comment: you have a very dangerous error, you are using same `id` for different elements, `id` must be unique, never repeat. use class instead

Comment: Those are classes I typed it wrong thx

Comment: @MShack Besides the duplicate #ids Mr. Nunes has pointed out, your examples conflict. The first example has a table that's mangled by divs. The second example of the desired result is a clean layout of forms. You need to do more than just append inputs you need to rip out that badly designed table as well.

Comment: no access to change existing HTML

Comment: What do you think `appendTo()` does? It changes existing HTML. Did you understand what I was saying? Example 1 has a crappy table but in Example 2 (the one you want as the result) doesn't have a table.

Comment: example 1 in full existing HTML , example 2 , is just the form portion of the existing HTML i want to look like

Comment: This is close , but multiple input show  $('input[type="submit"]').each(
    function(){
       $(this).detach().appendTo('.trades-form');
    });

Answer (score -1):

I tried this in your fiddle and it seemed to work.  Now you just need to tie it in to run after the dom loads to properly use it.

```
function tryThis(){
var submits = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']");


//now start at the top and work your way down with forms
  var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
  //
  if(submits.length != forms.length){
    alert("There are unequal numbers of forms and submits");
    return;
  }
  for(var i = 0;i<submits.length;i++){
     var currentSubmit = submits[i];
     currentSubmit.parentNode.removeChild(currentSubmit);
     forms[i].appendChild(currentSubmit);
  }

}
```